# Is there a piezo element in the KiCad libraries?

Tags: simulation, kicad, symbol

I have been trying to find a piezo element in the library but it just does not show up (I am using a Mac.) What should I do? If possible, please share a schematic with the piezo element in it so that I can copy it or a link to download the necessary library.  If not, can you suggest a new software for simulation that has all the elements and runs on a Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Preface: Mac, PC, Linux, Kicad runs on them all.

If it's just the piezo symbol you're looking for, you can create a symbol quite easy yourself, or usually there are libraries and symbols on the internet that can be downloaded.

However, if you want one for simulation, some look outside the ngspice(*) box can be necessary, often you will find LTspice simulations - those can be used with ltspice support enabled for ngspice.

(*)Ngspice = the builtin SPICE simulation in Kicad.

Answer (score 0):

The chances of finding a component like that in a built-in library are very slim, so I wouldn't hold out hope that another CAD program would be any better. However, KiCad makes it very easy to add new components. Either use the distributor or manufacturer's website to find the relevant models and add them to your project's library or use the datasheet to make your own. There are plenty of guides out there to walk you through both.

Comment: Just piezo symbols are null, I've searched for it a while ago myself.